# Hard Disk formatted accidentally with mkfs.ext4 in ubuntu, any chance to recover data?any chance to get data back?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem, data-recovery

i was trying to clean the linux systen with live usb, after installing ubuntu 18.04 i tried to load data from external hard disk but accidentally i put command mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb and it formatted the whole hard drive and changed the file system also. is there any chance or process to recover the data. please help?

Comment: There is a chance, but do not keep using hard drive and will need at least another hard/USB drive of equal or bigger size.  Test disk/photorec are the two most common programs used, but are others.  You will need to read up/google data recovery linux.

Comment: another worthy reminder to always make a backup of essential data before undertaking any procedure which likely results in formatting a HD. Sorry to press the point - always easier to benefit from hindsight but a salutary lesson to others contemplating such a procedure.